# Inserting multiple rows

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to populate multiple rows of a table with values from another table and I'm a bit stuck. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT radocs_id FROM radocs ORDER BY radocs_id DESC LIMIT 1,
SELECT crew_id FROM crew,
INSERT INTO signed (radocs_id, crew_id) Values ('radocs_id', 'crew_id');
```

`SELECT radocs_id FROM radocs ORDER BY radocs_id DESC LIMIT 1,` (returns a single entry as expected)

`SELECT crew_id FROM crew,` (returns multiple entries as expected)

I want to create an entries in the table called 'signed' for every individual 'crew_id' with the unique 'radocs_id' but `INSERT INTO signed (radocs_id, crew_id) Values ('radocs_id', 'crew_id')` doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong or is this the wrong way to go about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is relation between `crew.crew_id` and `radocs.radocs_id`? How your resulting set should be constructed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO signed 
(SELECT crew_id,(select radocs_id FROM radocs
                 ORDER BY radocs_id DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM crew)
```

Comment: And why is that? @Daan

Comment: Because it's not a valid query.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that gets the rows you want:

```
SELECT r.radocs_id, c.crew_id
FROM (SELECT radocs_id
      FROM radocs 
      ORDER BY radocs_id DES
      LIMIT 1
     ) r CROSS JOIN
     crews c;
```

Then the insert is:

```
INSERT INTO signed(radocs_id, crew_id)
    SELECT r.radocs_id, c.crew_id
    FROM (SELECT radocs_id
          FROM radocs 
          ORDER BY radocs_id DES
          LIMIT 1
         ) r CROSS JOIN
         crews c;
```

Comment: I don't think i explained myself very well, there is no relationship between crew_id and radocs_id. I current have a form that logs risk assessment documents into the 'radocs' table, the 'crew' table lists all of the staff at the venue. What i want to achieve is to insert an entry into the 'signed' table for every unique crew_id where the radocs_id is a defined value (the last entry in the radocs table.

Comment: @DCampan . . . That should be what this is doing.